# "Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int64'. While Deserializing JSON String

Tags: c#, json.net

I am parsing a large data file with JSON elements in C#.  Deserialization fails for some strings with the error below.

```
 Exception  = Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int64'.
 Message    = Error converting value 3/28/2172 12:00:00 AM to type 'System.Int64'.  Path 'ProductDetail.productId', line 1, position 4003."
```

The error doesn't occur for all strings, but seems to suggest the value is being interpreted as a DateTime value; although, it's defined as a **long** within the associated class.

Can I force the value to be interpreted as a **long**?

ProductDetail.productId is defined as a member of the following type:

```
   public class ProductDetail
    {
        public string accreditedInvestorInd { get; set; }
        public string accrueAcreteInd { get; set; }
        public DateTime issueDate { get; set; }
        // ... truncated for simplicity

        public long productId { get; set; }

       // ... truncated for simplicity
        public string wkndHolPayInd { get; set; }
        public string zeroCouponInd { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried unsuccessfully to use a converter attribute with the hope of forcing a different interpretation.  (Not sure if I'm using it correctly)...

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(string))]
    public long productId { get; set; }
```

Also, I am using a custom DateTime format.

Here is a subset of the large data file I am trying to deserialize that corresponds to `ProductDetail`:

```
{"accrueAcreteInd":"Y","callableInd":"Y","calledInd":"N","cpnCurrency":"USD","cpnPmtFreqCode":"S","cpnRate":"2.8","curAmtOutstanding":"7825000.0","currencyCode":"USD","cusip":"3130H0AX1","datedDate":"20160303","dayCountMonthCode":"30","dayCountYearCode":"360","daysToSettle":"1","dtcEligibleInd":"Y","eomPmtInd":"N","exchange":"TRACE","fatcaCode":"1","firstCpnPmtDate":"20160901","hqlaCode":"2A","identifier":"3130H0AX1","identifierType":"cusip","inDefaultInd":"N","infoSourceCode":"R21RB","intAccrued":".91777778","intTypeCode":"FIX","is144aInd":"N","issueCountry":"US","issueDate":"20160303","issuePrice":"100.0","issuerIndustryCode":"11","issuerName":"FARMER MAC","issuerTicker":"FAMCA","lastCpnPmtDate":"20250901","lastUpdateTime":"20160830","lastUpdateTimeExt":"00:06:58","longDesc":"FAMCA 2.8 03/01/2026","maturityDate":"20260301","minDenom":"1000.0","minParAmount":"1000.0","mktSectorDes":"Govt","mtnInd":"Y","nextCallDate":"20170301","nextCallPrice":"100.0","nextCpnPmtDate":"20170301","origIssueAmt":"7825000.0","prevCpnPmtDate":"20160901","primaryIssInd":"Y","privatePlacementInd":"N","productId":"21720328","productTypeCode":"FRMNT","putableInd":"N","pxCleanInd":"Y","redempVal":"100.0","regSInd":"N","restrictedInd":"N","secHoldInd":"N","securityType":"FAMCCL","series":"NOTZ","shortDesc":"FAMCA 2.8 03/26","sinkableInd":"N","traceEligibleInd":"N","truePutInd":"N","wkndHolPayInd":"N","zeroCouponInd":"N"}
```

And here is how I am trying to deserialize the subset, where `Line` is the JSON string above:

```
var dateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatString = "yyyyMMdd" };
var detail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductDetail>(Line, dateFormatSettings);
```

And here is the full exception for the simplified JSON:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value 3/28/2172 12:00:00 AM to type 'System.Int64'. Path 'productId', line 1, position 1117. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int64'.
   at System.DateTime.System.IConvertible.ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

Comment: `[JsonConverter(typeof(string))]` will definitely throw an exception.  The type passed into the [`JsonConvererAttribute` constructor](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute__ctor.htm) is supposed to be the **[custom converter type](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)** not the target type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the specific `DateFormatString` you are using:

```
var dateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatString = "yyyyMMdd" };
```

JSON has no [literal syntax for dates](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm) and so, at a low level, Json.NET does some pattern matching to recognize strings that are dates, using the [`DateFormatString`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatString.htm) setting.  Unfortunately your `DateFormatString` setting of `yyyyMMdd` matches both of the following JSON properties:

```
   "issueDate":"20160303", // Should deserialize to a DateTime
   "productId":"21720328", // Should deserialize to a long
```

And so, while the first is correctly recognized as a date, the second is also, eventually causing the `"Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int64'."` exception at a higher code level.  It's a bit of an edge case since it's unexpected for a JSON string value corresponding to a `long` member to be parsable as both a `long` and a `DateTime`, but this is arguably a bug in Json.NET.

You have a couple workarounds:

1. Disable automatic date recognition by setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm):

   ```
   var dateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
       DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
       DateFormatString = "yyyyMMdd"
   };
   ```

   Members explicitly typed as `DateTime` will still be correctly deserialized despite disabling low-level automatic recognition.
2. Use an `IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMdd" }` rather than setting `JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString`.

   ```
   var dateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
       Converters = { new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMdd" } }
   };
   ```

   Members explicitly typed as `DateTime` will be deserialized using your desired format string while leaving the pattern used for low-level automatic recognition unchanged.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QnZFUW) reproducing the problem and demonstrating the two workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and added information.  The entire code block didn't post for some reason.  Setting DateParseHandling to None did allow me to workaround the issue.  I will look into your second suggestion regarding the use of an IsoDateTimeConverter.

Comment: @user7355274 - was I correct in guessing the `JsonSerializerSettings` you were using?  If so I can edit your question to include them.

Comment: Yes, your guess was correct.  FYI - Using the IsoDateTimeConverter worked as well.  Thanks again.  I spent quite a bit of time in all the wrong places trying to resolve this one.